# Angular pre-selected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I have a modal that can edit. But in my modal I cant pre-select.

This is my HTML

```
<select ng-model='names.productionType' ng-options="data for data in productionType"></select>
```

This is my Script

```
$scope.productionType =[
  "Article LP Composition",
  "Normal LP Composition",
  "Reading Material",
  "Transcribed Manuscript",
  "LP Production"
];
```

So far this is what I tried

HTML

```
<select ng-model='editable.productionType' ng-options="data for data in productionType" ng-selected="editable.productionType='{{names.production_type}}'"></select>
```

In my script

```
$scope.names.productionType = "Normal LP Composition";
```

It will pre selected but the problem is I cant select other **options**

Comment: Your `ng-selected="editable.productionType='{{names.production_type}}'"` shouldn't have brackets. You can remove the whole `ng-selected` because angular will figure out that your `ng-model` is equal to one of the options, then select it. See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6cu3u8s/)

Comment: @devqon but when I changed the pre selected on submit it will not give the new value in modal when I submit.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `$scope.names` firstly then add `productionType` proerty to it.

```
 <select ng-model='names.productionType' ng-options="data as data for data in productionType">
  </select>

$scope.names ={};
$scope.names.productionType = "Normal LP Composition";
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.productionType = [
    "Article LP Composition",
    "Normal LP Composition",
    "Reading Material",
    "Transcribed Manuscript",
    "LP Production"
  ];
  $scope.names = {};
  $scope.names.productionType = "Normal LP Composition";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select ng-model='names.productionType' ng-options="data as data for data in productionType">
  </select>
  {{names.productionType}}
</div>
```

Comment: the $scope.names what declared already in modal so it was something like this `var productionModal = function($scope, $uibModalInstance, $uibModal, $http, items){$scope.names = items;}`

Comment: Why  `$scope.names = items;`?

Comment: nvrm about that one but the problem is when im gonna select the other options the it always return to **"Normal LP Composition"** when im gonna submit it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model='names.productionType' ng-value="data.productionType" ng-options="data.productionType for data in productionType"></select>
```